# CertificateExpiredException in WebView Android

Tags: android, webview

I have a webapp that use a https server. I some point the logcat throws this error and the URL does not load.

I have already try this in my Application Class

```
try {
            SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try
        {
            ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(getApplicationContext());
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And this

```
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```

The log is the same

```
2021-06-25 08:46:24.103 4888-9889/? E/CastSocket: [TcpProberDeviceController-1] SSLException encountered. Tearing down the socket.
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Certificate expired at Wed Jun 16 15:45:17 GMT-03:00 2021 (compared to Fri Jun 25 08:46:24 GMT-03:00 2021)
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.SSLUtils.toSSLHandshakeException(:com.google.android.gms@212116018@21.21.16 (040308-378233385):2)
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.convertException(:com.google.android.gms@212116018@21.21.16 (040308-378233385):1)
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextData(:com.google.android.gms@212116018@21.21.16 (040308-378233385):4)
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(:com.google.android.gms@212116018@21.21.16 (040308-378233385):30)
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(:com.google.android.gms@212116018@21.21.16 (040308-378233385):46)
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(:com.google.android.gms@212116018@21.21.16 (040308-378233385):5)
        at sdc.c(:com.google.android.gms@212116018@21.21.16 (040308-378233385):6)
        at sdh.c(:com.google.android.gms@212116018@21.21.16 (040308-378233385):51)
        at sdg.run(:com.google.android.gms@212116018@21.21.16 (040308-378233385):2)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
     Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: Certificate expired at Wed Jun 16 15:45:17 GMT-03:00 2021 (compared to Fri Jun 25 08:46:24 GMT-03:00 2021)
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509Certificate.checkValidity(:com.google.android.gms@212116018@21.21.16 (040308-378233385):3)
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509Certificate.checkValidity(:com.google.android.gms@212116018@21.21.16 (040308-378233385):1)
        at say.checkServerTrusted(:com.google.android.gms@212116018@21.21.16 (040308-378233385):4)
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(:com.google.android.gms@212116018@21.21.16 (040308-378233385):8)
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.verifyCertificateChain(:com.google.android.gms@212116018@21.21.16 (040308-378233385):6)
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.ENGINE_SSL_read_direct(Native Method)
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.readDirectByteBuffer(:com.google.android.gms@212116018@21.21.16 (040308-378233385):2)
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextDataDirect(:com.google.android.gms@212116018@21.21.16 (040308-378233385):0)
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextDataHeap(:com.google.android.gms@212116018@21.21.16 (040308-378233385):3)
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextData(:com.google.android.gms@212116018@21.21.16 (040308-378233385):3)
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(:com.google.android.gms@212116018@21.21.16 (040308-378233385):30) 
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(:com.google.android.gms@212116018@21.21.16 (040308-378233385):46) 
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(:com.google.android.gms@212116018@21.21.16 (040308-378233385):5) 
        at sdc.c(:com.google.android.gms@212116018@21.21.16 (040308-378233385):6) 
        at sdh.c(:com.google.android.gms@212116018@21.21.16 (040308-378233385):51) 
        at sdg.run(:com.google.android.gms@212116018@21.21.16 (040308-378233385):2) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

I have not access to the server

Comment: "I have not access to the server" -- contact the server owners and tell them to update their SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like certificate that you used will expire 16th of June 2021.
But you have the error because on you device system date is 2021-06-25(25th of June).
Try to set actual date on the device. (Like a temporary fix)

But, anyway it will be expired tomorrow. (it will work until Jun 16 15:45:17)
And you will have the same error again. So you should contact server side team and ask them to update the TLS certificate.